# Read a constant number of characters from a BufferedReader over a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I've set up a socket client in Java and am reading in data using a `BufferedReader`. I am aware that the `reader.readLine()` method will read a single line of input from the stream. However, I would like to read a constant number of characters into a string, or until the end of the stream, regardless of the content of the data read.

For example:

```
BufferedReader reader = ...
String data = /* next 1024 characters from the stream */
```

Comment: `readLine()` will return when it reaches the end of the stream. Of course, the stream has to actually end...

Comment: @JonSkeet According to the JavaDocs a `readLine()` will return the text until it is terminated by a linefeed or a carriage return character.

Comment: The docs aren't as clear as they might be, but it really *does* return the line if the end of the stream is reached. It's very easy for you to verify that.

Comment: My original wording was very vague and I don't believe I succeeded in actually explaining what I was trying to figure out. This updated question better describes the solution I was looking for, which is answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the read process into a loop...

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(128);

String text = null;
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    data.append(text).append("\n"); // if you're interested in the new line character
}

return data.toString();
```

Your `recv` method should be throwing the `IOException`, as it's not really up to this method to deal with these error (IMHO)

**Updated**

If you can't guarantee that the line will be terminated by the a new line, you need to read each value from it...

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(128);

int charsIn = -1;
char buffer = new char[1024];
while ((charsIn = reader.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    data.append(buffer, 0, charsIn);
}

return data;
```

Now, the problem is, the stream actually won't end cause it doesn't make sense in the context of a `Socket` stream (it has no end until it's closed).

Here it becomes imperative that the sender is sending a terminating character to allow you to break the loop.

**Updated**

```
char buffer = new char[1024];
// This will read UP TO 1024 characters from buffer into the
// character array, starting at position 0.
// This may read less then 1024 characters if the underlying
// stream returns -1 indicating and end of stream from
// the read method
int charsIn = reader.read(buffer, 0, 1024);

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(charsIn);
data.append(buffer, 0, charsIn);
```

Comment: I have my program already repeating the `recv` method to receive more then one line, but the issue that I'm having is that the data I am receiving may not end with a newline character or contain any newline characters at all.

Comment: How to you determine the end of line?

Comment: I am not using this program for any specific project at the moment, but would rather like to establish a flexible way to send data over sockets in the future. Is there any way I can receive up to a certain number of characters, as in Python's `socket.recv(1024)` method?

Comment: Sure, have a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for [`BufferedReader#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28char[],%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: I've looked at this before, although as I said, I'm a beginner to Java and it doesn't make much sense to me. Is it possible you could include an example of this receiving up to `1024` characters and explain how it works and what the arguments mean? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm beginning to understand it now. Last of all, why is `new StringBuilder(128)` passed `128` as opposed to the length of the array `1024`? And is the best way to convert a StringBuilder object to a String using the `toString()` method?

Comment: Sorry, convention on my part.  If you know you'll be receiving 1024 characters, then you can specify that.  I'll correct it.  And yes to `toString`